# Replace and Concat an image HTML String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array named Sport with almost 20 items and I need to replace an image HTML string with global replacement (/string/g), my string contains HTML tags. This is an example:

```
//Sports array
var sport = ['soccer','tennis','pool','basketball'];

//Original string
var original = 'Hello, do you play <img width="20" src="img/soccer.png"/> ?';

//New string
var newstring;

//If original string contains an image html of some sports from array,replace with :sport[item]:
for (var i = 0; i < sport.Length; i++)
{
   newstring = original.replace('/<img width="20" src="img\/icons\/'+sport[i]+'.png"/>/g',':'+sport[i]+':');
}
```

So, recap... I need to replace this

```
<img width="20" src="img/soccer.png"/>
```

To this

```
:soccer:
```

The result should be:
Hello, do you play :soccer:?

Comment: what is you requirement?? Please post a https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Looks like you've mixed RegExp literal and a string in the `replace` argument. Create a RegExp to use with a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description), or remove the RegExp literal parts from the string.

Comment: hi, i need to replace a string that could contain IMG tags, and this img tag replace by :sport: (as literal as you read and saw in the example from above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace this :

```
newstring = original.replace('/<img width="20" src="img\/icons\/'+sport[i]+'.png"/>/g',':'+sport[i]+':');
```

to this :

```
newstring = original.replace(new RegExp('<img width="20" src="img\/icons\/'+sport[i]+'.png"\/>', 'g'),':'+sport[i]+':');
```

because you can't concatenate string in "inline" regex (if someone knows the right name, please comment) :

```
// no quotes around pattern
newString = myString.replace(/pattern/g, "foo")
```

You should have a look at this answer : [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144788/3484498)

---

#### Edit :

If you have troubles with special characters (from the answer quoted) :

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}


// Use :
var newString = replaceAll(myString,"pattern", "replace_with_this");
```

In your example :

```
for (var i = 0; i < sport.length; i++)
{
    newstring = replaceAll(
                    // original String
                    original,
                    // pattern
                    '<img width="20" src="img/icons/'+sport[i]+'.png"/>',
                    // replace with :
                    ':'+sport[i]+':');
}
```

**note:** in `replaceAll` you don't have to escape your pattern, it is done by the `escapeRegExp` function

Comment: yep, there's a problem with the html string part that i want to replace, it works with a single word or without special chars